# Form becomes unusable after API is called

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a Windows Application that is calling a Third Party API:

```
    return fsDesktopApi.FindAndViewDocument(fsCabinetName, searchCriteria);
```

The calling application leaves a Form open that can't be moved or minimized until the resulting displayed document is closed. Is there a way that I can call this API without leaving my form in this inert state?

Comment: You probably want to call that in a background thread.

Comment: How do I do that Slaks?

Answer (score 2):

As the call seems to block the UI thread, preventing it from handling messages from the OS, you could run the call within a separate thread:

```
var thread = new Thread(() => fsDesktopApi.FindAndViewDocument(fsCabinetName, searchCriteria));
thread.Start();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code happens on the same thread as the UI, so you can't do anything until it processes the action. You have multiple ways of doing asynchronous stuff, for instance

[Threading](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=12&checkda=1&ct=1425487661&rver=6.0.5276.0&wp=MCMBI&wlcxt=msdn%24msdn%24msdn&wreply=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Faa645740%2528v%3Dvs.71%2529.aspx&lc=1033&id=254354&mkt=en-US)
[Async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)
[BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)
[Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx)

And so on. Do some research on the topic and pick the one that's the most appropriate for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use a BackgroundWorker.  Here's a simple (incomplete) example.

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += CallApi;
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += ApiCallComplete;

private void CallApi(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //read & cast fsCabinetName & searchCriteria from e.Argument
    e.Result =  fsDesktopApi.FindAndViewDocument(fsCabinetName, searchCriteria);
}

private void ApiCallComplete(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     //cast and read result from e.Result after checking for exception or cancellation & handle on UI thread.
}
```

Then you can just call your worker as such to start:

```
    worker.RunWorkerAsync(/*Pass Your Argument Object Here*/);
```